# The captcha appears in an inconvenient location on Android

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web, captcha

The captcha appears in an inconvenient location on [Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361272/178179) and [Opera Mobile on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser).

E.g. I saw the following after trying to post a question:

[image: Captcha not visible on default view]

I had to zoom out or horizontally scroll to see where the captcha was:

[image: Captcha on the far right on a zoomed-out view]

I believe I was using the responsive design.

Comment: Well, that browser appears under "it still may work, but with a degraded experience" in the "supported browsers" faq, so it's expected to have some issues.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance thanks good to know, I wasn't aware of this FAQ. Is the captcha appearing properly on supported web browsers?

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this (never got Captcha when posting), so can't tell for sure, but most likely it was tested on the major browsers, yes.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance I only know how to get this Captcha window when actually posting questions or answers, which isn't a clean way to reproduce :-/

Comment: Can post answer to sand box here. How to reproduce it?

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance thanks, it seems I get the captcha when I post a few questions or answers within a short period of time. E.g. 10 posts in 5 minutes should get you a captcha I think, unless if captchas are disabled in the sandbox (which might be the case as it isn't publicly available).

Comment: I've just gone [through the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361272/364217) in Chrome on my Android.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 thanks, good to know!