# Verify you're not a robot in mobile

Tags: bug, captcha, responsive-design

A few moments ago, I was asking a question on Hermeneutics Stack Exchange and a dialog appeared to verify I'm not a robot.

Even though I don't have a picture and don't know how to trigger it again, what I got was something not responsive. More specifically, I had to scroll to the side in order to check the captcha.

Comment: Beep beep, whirr, boop beep?

Comment: @rene you're right, couldn't find it when was searching. That was exactly the behavior.

Comment: If you've reproduced this on a different browser, feel free to add a comment under the linked post stating that fact.

Comment: @41686d6564 thank you, I've done that.

Comment: Captcha has it's reasons.